# iPhone music streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, core-audio, audio

I'm trying to send music over bluetooth from one iOS device to another. I've been using [this](https://github.com/abbood/audioSamplingToAudioQueue) to build packets like in Ray Wenderlich's SNAP tutorial, but I've been having trouble reconstructing the packet information on the receiving phone. I have tried using https://github.com/abbood/iphoneAudioSyncer but I think it is too complicated for my needs (since I do not need synced playing). What is the simplest buffer approach that accounts for things like lost/out of order packets? I have read through a lot of CoreAudio stuff but it is very dense, so I would appreciate help from someone who has tackled this type of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you talk about los/out of order packets.. you're talking about the topic of [Packet Loss Concealment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss_concealment).. which is a very dense topic (I mean if you think core audio is dense.. wait till you dive into PLC).

In a nutshell, there are many ways to deal with packet loss.. but the simplest way (which I advise you to do) is to replace the lost packets with silence (same goes with out of order packets.. if a packet is out of order.. just discard it).

that being said.. you are dealing with audio that is streamed to you (ie sent via the bluetooth/wifi network).. which means in almost 100% of the time it's compressed audio you're getting (ie Variable Bit Rate audio VBR).. if you simply try to substitute lost VBR packets with silence.. you'll run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565904/core-audio-is-zero-equivalent-to-silence-only-for-pcm-audio) problem. You'll either have to insert silence packets in the same compression format as the VBR audio you're dealing with, or you will have to convert your VBR compressed audio into non-compressed audio (Lossless PCM), then insert zeros in place of the missing packets.

Comment: You'll notice that although you used two of the sample apps I created, you'll still finding it very difficult. Unfortunately that's the reality of core audio/real time apps in general. There are no easy way around it or plug and play solutions you can simply find on the web (and if there is, just understanding them is a very difficult task on it's own.. as you've found out).

Comment: So This is the advice I give to everyone attempting to get into a core audio/real time app (weather for commercial or academic purposes, and you're not the first): you may have to reevaluate the scope of the project, because such projects may seem easy at first look, but once you dig in, you'll find out that the rabbit hole extends far deeper than you've anticipated. Said another way, the solution of this problem starts at the beginning of the your software devleopment life cycle: at the planning and requirements gathering phase.

Comment: What are some alternatives that you would recommend? Spotify premium is an obvious first choice but how about uploading/downloading the songs to a server. Basically how can we let people make music suggestions and have the songs play on a host phone?

Comment: @tancik I'm kinda lost here.. Spotify premium? isn't that an already made solution? there are tonnes out there (but I thought you had to code one yourself?) uploading/downloading songs from a server makes your job a lot more easier.. There are tons of plug and play audio streaming servers out there and hooking it with iOS is easy.. "Basically how can we let people make music suggestions and have the songs play on a host phone" You'll have to make that question more specific..